# Table widths changing when email testing in 'Outlook 2013 DPI 120'

Tags: html, outlook, html-table, html-email, dpi

I'm building an email and for some reason my table widths alter when viewing in Outlook 2013 DPI 120. This is a new email client added into Litmus so I'm not sure how to fix. I have three tables in one full width table and the widths are changing, breaking the layout. Any ideas how to fix?

```html
    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" class="fullWidth" style=
"padding:0px; margin:0px;border:1px #333 solid;" width="178">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding:20px;">
            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
            width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="color:white;text-align:center;padding:10px 5px;font-size:13px;             
font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;border-bottom:1px solid #fff;">
                    <strong>A title</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It is fine in every other client.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to [Outlook scaling the content to a larger size](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/151-mystery-solved-dpi-scaling-in-outlook-2007-2013), forcing your images and other declared items to resize. This can destroy your layout and there is really nothing you can do to change it - it is a setting client-side on the subscribers computer.

Your best way to fix this is to use [MSO conditionals](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/) to wrap into a single table and separate each column into a separate td. Or to use the [TD or TH stack](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/4321/order-stacked-columns-responsive-email) ([TD no longer works in Android](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how_android_is_strangling_responsive_design)) with media queries. Outlook will stretch the table to fit two columns, but will not stretch the table to fit two tables, it will instead force the second table below the first.